# If $\frac{z+1}{z-1} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta $, where $\theta \ne 0 $, show that $z = -i\cot \left(\frac{\theta }{2} \right)$.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

If $\frac{z+1}{z-1}=\cos \theta +i\sin \theta $, where $\theta \ne 0
$, show that $z=-i\cot \left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)$.

My attempt:

$z+1=(z-1)(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta )=z\cos \theta +iz\sin \theta 
-\cos \theta -i\sin \theta $

This means that: $z\cos \theta +iz\sin \theta -z=1+\cos \theta +i\sin 
\theta $

Therefore: $z(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta -1)=1+\cos \theta +i\sin \theta 
$

And so: $z=\frac{1+\cos \theta +i\sin \theta }{\cos \theta +i\sin 
\theta -1}$

I'd appreciate any insight on how to proceed with this question.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Let me define $\alpha=\frac{\theta}{2}$, so that $\theta=2\alpha$. Hopefully you remember the double angle formulae. We have
\begin{align}
z&=\frac{[\cos (2\alpha) + 1]+i\sin (2\alpha)}{[\cos(2\alpha)-1]+i\sin(2\alpha)}\\
&=\frac{[2\cos^2\alpha] + 2i\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{[-2\sin^2\alpha]+2i\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}\\
&=\frac{\cos^2(\alpha)+i\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{-\sin^2\alpha+i\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}\\
&=\frac{-i\cos(\alpha)[i\cos\alpha - \sin\alpha]}{\sin(\alpha)[-\sin\alpha+i\cos\alpha]}\\
&=-i\cot(\alpha)\\
&=-i\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right).
\end{align}